# Take users to specific pages based on their roles using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in MySQL database which stores users and their roles say, admin and student.
So I want when admin logs in, is taken to the admin dashboard and a student is taken to the student home page respectively.

How do I redirect the two users to respective pages based on their roles?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: first you try it and show us code what you done?

Comment: What have your tried so far?? so want to redirect to their specific pages after login or they cannot see each others pages. please explain.

Comment: I'm going to attach what I have attempted but for now I have two navbars one for admin and another for staff. I have succeeded in redirecting user to login if they don't belong to that role. But now the challenge is redirecting them at login page using sessions. #danish-khan-I

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give them specific role (admin, srudent) for example, and after login, do something like this

$role = get role from your database;

if(role == 'admin'){ then redirect admin panel}

elseif(role=='student'){redirect to student place}

else{redirect to another place}

Comment: i'm sorry but i am  new here so i don't know how i can attach my code. but it seems its taking the first if and ignoring the else statement

Comment: it has finally worked with your answer. thanks alot #Lasha Pareshishvili.

Answer (score 1):

1.) First Add user type in database table field, Your database table structure like that:-

```
table:-
    id    username   password   Role 
    1      ---         ----     admin
    2       ---        ----     Student
    3       ----        ----    Teacher
```

I think your problem is checking the condition ,use if and else statements.

```
 $_SESSION['username'] = $name[0];
  $_SESSION['password'] = $name[1];
  $_SESSION['Role'] = $name[2];


if($_SESSION['Role'] == 'admin'){
   header("Location: admin.php");
   }
else if($_SESSION['Role'] == 'Student'){
   header("Location: Student.php");
   }
else if($_SESSION['Role'] == 'Teacher'){
   header("Location: Teacher.php");
   }
else{
   echo "Your not logged in";
   }
```

Hope it Helps you....

Answer (score 1):

***this worked for me. Thanks for your help...***

```
<?php if (isset($conn,$_POST['login'])) {
                   $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["username"]);  
                   $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["password"]);  
                   $sql = "SELECT * FROM staff WHERE Domain = '$username'";  
                   $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);  
           if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
           {  
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
                {  
                     if(password_verify($password, $row["Pass"]))  
                     {  
                          //return true;  
                          $_SESSION["username"] = $username;
                          $role=$row['Role'];

                          if($role == 'Admin'){ 
                           header("location: dashboard.php");
                          }

                          elseif($role=='Staff'){
                           header("location: index.php");

                          }

                          else{
                           header("location: login.php");
                          } 
                     }  
                     else {  
                          //return false;  
                          echo '<script>alert("Wrong User Password")</script>'; 
                          }  
                }  
           }  
           else  
           {  
                echo '<script>alert("Sorry! No such User Name is found")</script>';  
           }    

                    } 
                ?>
```